# SSIS box.com file

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012, box

I have SSIS file system task that I use for copy file. 
the source here is  \\192.168.1.100\folder\file.xlsx.
And then I copy this file at same location as \\192.168.1.100\folder\file_today's_date.xlsx using variables.

But Now we are moving to box cloud.
We can access box using this address https:\dav.box.com
There is no fixed IP address for this web address.
I can not use this address instead of my UNC path above in SSIS.
Whats the best way to resolve this? Can u please suggest anything here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you contacted box?

Comment: I did not get any satisfactory reply from them. So just wondering if anyone else has tried something like this or not. Thanks again.